# How can I make this kind of aggregation in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that has categorical columns and numerical columns, and I want some agrupation on the values on numerical columns (max, min, sum...) depending on the value of the cateogorical ones (so I have to create new columns for each value that each cateogorical column can take).

To make it more understable, it's better to put a toy example.

Say that I have this dataframe:

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.DataFrame({
     'ref' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
     'value_type' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A'],
     'amount' : [100, 50, 20, 300, 150, 70]
}).set_index(['ref'])
```

```
    value_type  amount
ref     
1      A      100
1      B      50
1      A      20
2      C      300
2      C      150
3      A      70
```

And I want to group the amounts on the values of value_type, grouping also for each reference. The result in this case (supposing that only the sum was needed) will be this one:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({
    'ref' : [1, 2, 3],
    'sum_amount_A' : [120, 0, 70],
    'sum_amount_B' : [50, 0, 0],
    'sum_amount_C' : [0, 450, 0]
}).set_index('ref')
```

```
    sum_amount_A    sum_amount_B    sum_amount_C
ref         
1        120         50                   0
2        0           0                    450
3        70          0                    0
```

I have tried something that works but it's extremely inefficient. It takes several minutes to process 30.000 rows aprox.

What I have done is this: (I have a dataframe with an only row for each index ref, called df_final)

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['ref'])

for ref in df_grouped.groups:
    df_aux = df.loc[[ref]]
    column = 'A' # I have more columns, but for illustration one is enough
    for value in df_aux[column].unique():
        df_aux_column_value = df_aux.loc[df_aux[column] == value]
        df_final.at[ref,'sum_' + column + '_' + str(value)] = np.sum(df_aux_columna_valor[column])
```

I'm sure there should be better ways of doing this aggretation... Thanks in advance!!

EDIT:

The answer given is correct when there is only one column to group by. In the real dataframe I have several columns on which I want to calculate some agg functions, but on the values on each column separately. I mean that I don't want an aggregated value for each combination of the values of the column, but only for the columns by themselves.

Let's make an example.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ref' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    'sexo' : ['Hombre', 'Hombre', 'Hombre', 'Mujer', 'Mujer', 'Hombre'],
    'lugar_trabajo' : ['Campo', 'Ciudad', 'Campo', 'Ciudad', 'Ciudad', 'Campo'],
    'dificultad' : ['Alta', 'Media', 'Alta', 'Media', 'Baja', 'Alta'],
    'amount' : [100, 50, 20, 300, 150, 70]
}).set_index(['ref'])
```

This dataframe looks like that:

```
   sexo lugar_trabajo   dificultad  amount
ref             
1   Hombre  Campo       Alta         100
1   Hombre  Ciudad      Media        50
1   Hombre  Campo       Alta         20
2   Mujer   Ciudad      Media        300
2   Mujer   Ciudad      Baja         150
3   Hombre  Campo       Alta         70
```

If I group by several columns, or make a pivot table (which in a way is equivalent, as far as I know), doing this:

```
df.pivot_table(index='ref',columns=['sexo','lugar_trabajo','dificultad'],values='amount',aggfunc=[np.sum,np.min,np.max,len], dropna=False)
```

I will get a dataframe with 48 columns (because I have 3 * 2 * 2 different values, and 4 agg functions).

A way of achieve the result that I want is this:

```
df_agregado = pd.DataFrame(df.index).set_index('ref')

for col in ['sexo','lugar_trabajo','dificultad']:
    df_agregado = pd.concat([df_agregado, df.pivot_table(index='ref',columns=[col],values='amount',aggfunc=[np.sum,np.min,np.max,len])],axis=1)
```

I do each group by alone, and concat all of them. In this way I get 28 columns (2 * 4 + 3 * 4 + 2 * 4). It works and it's fast, but it's not very elegant. Is there another way of getting this result??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more efficient way is to use Pandas built-in functions instead of `for` loops. There are two main steps that you should take.
First, you need to groupby not only by index, but also by index and the column:

```
res = df.groupby(['ref','value_type']).sum()
print(res)
```

The output is like this at this step:

```
                amount
ref value_type        
1   A              120
    B               50
2   C              450
3   A               70
```

Second, you need to unstack the multi index, as follows:

```
df2 = res.unstack(level='value_type',fill_value=0)
```

The output will be your desire output:

```
    amount
value_type  A   B   C
ref         
1   120 50  0
2   0   0   450
3   70  0   0
```

As an optional step you can use `droplevel` to flatten it:

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel()
```

```
value_type  A   B   C
ref         
1   120 50  0
2   0   0   450
3   70  0   0
```

Comment: I have edited the question, because when working with several columns the group by operation it's (in my case) not what I want... Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the EDIT section, I can think of the same idea that you had. Groupby each column with 'ref' and then concat the result. Let me see if there is a better way.